# What is the formal term to describe the columns space between matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology

Suppose I have two matrices,

$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\1 & 0\end{bmatrix}~~ B=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 & 1 \\1 & 0 & 0\\\end{bmatrix}
$$

What is the terminology to say the relationship between A and B's columns space? Can I say they have same column space? Or A's column space is a subspace of B?

Comment: Why would you *not* be able to say that?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez not sure I am using the right math term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both have the same column space because they span the same vector space, which is probably $\mathbb R^2$ without context. Since a space is a subspace of itself (an easy exercise), you can also say that $A$'s column space is a subspace of $B$'s, and vice versa.